# AMPScript to Open a link in new Window

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to trigger two actions once a form is completed.

1. Automatically Download a PDF from a URL
2. Open up a thank you page

Following code is used to achieve this functionality:

```
%%[
Set @downloadurl = "link for pdf file"
Set @download_complete_url = Concat("http://",@downloadurl)
Redirect(@download_complete_url)
]%%

%%[
Set @url = "google.com"
Set @complete_url = Concat("http://",@url)
Redirect(@complete_url)
]%%
```

However when I submit the form it just opens up the `download_complete_url` but the `complete_url` does not opens up.

Is there a way to open a new pop-up window for the PDF download, so that the page can be directed to `complete_url`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take on it will be switching the order of your actions:
1: Open up a thank you page
2: Automatically Download a PDF from a URL

The reason for why your example isn't working, is the visitor being redirected to the thank you page, before the download redirect gets triggered. You cannot have two redirects from a single page.

You will need to open the PDF download from the thank you page instead.

**EDIT:**

You cannot have both redirects on one page. What I would do is redirect to a thank you page, and insert a script there, which retrieves the PDF - alternatively just a link to the file.

Comment: Hi Lukas,

Even if I reverse the order, still when the pdf opens up, the thank you page will be overridden with the pdf link.

I was hoping to automatically download the pdf. 

Thanks